# Weird Shrink/Fatten Scalling Problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, transforms

Quite the noob since I'm trying to learn how to use Blender for the first time (Sorta). That said, I've been experiencing a weird problem with the shrink/fatten tool as it appears to be shrinking one object, and fattening the other, even though they've all been selected, as shown in the gif within the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6gER.jpg

Don't know exactly what could be causing it, but possibly an easy solution can fix it.

Comment: Recalculate your normals. Select all vertices of the meshes in Edit Mode and press Ctrl + N.

Answer (score 3):

As Akados mentioned, there is a problem with your normals.

## What are normals?

Every face has a normal. It's the direction the face is pointing at. One side of every triangle is considered the "outer" side and the other is the "inner" side.

## Why is shrink/fatten confused?

When you use `shrink/fatten`, it moves the faces in the direction of the normals.

Fatten = move towards the "outer" side.
Shrink = move towards the "inner" side.

It makes sense when you think about it.

Since the "3" in your example has the correct normals, it works fine for that part of the mesh. But the "D" part seems to have flipped normals, so the `shrink/fatten` actually moves faces in the opposite direction.

## How to fix it?

Blender knows how to automatically get the normals right. You have to select everything in the mesh and `Make normals consistent`, using the shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.